# Could not create ASP.content_xxx_aspx

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

There is no error in program but when I'm trying to run it in IIS (Microsoft Edge) I get this error :

> Server could not create ASP.content_admin_matkul_aspx.

Stack Trace :

> [InvalidOperationException: Server could not create ASP.content_admin_matkul_aspx.]
>
> __ASP.FastObjectFactory_app_web_3bgnxvsl.Create_ASP_content_admin_matkul_aspx() +192
> System.Web.Compilation.BuildResultCompiledType.CreateInstance() +31
> Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls.FriendlyUrlRouteHandler.GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext) +22
> System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule.PostResolveRequestCache(HttpContextBase context) +9942213
> System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule.OnApplicationPostResolveRequestCache(Object sender, EventArgs e) +85
> System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +144
> System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +50
> System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +73

The error told me to add debug = true at the top of my .aspx file that generated the error and I've done that :

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" Debug="true" AutoEventWireup="false" 
         CodeBehind="matkul.aspx.vb" 
         Inherits="DeaniraFadrinaldi_BankSoalITSA.matkul"%>
```

Also adding compilation debug = "true" to the configuration file of my application (`web.config`) like this :

```
<compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.7.2"/>
```

But I still get the same error, hElP mEEee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED!!

I used the same name for my vb class and my web form. Apparently asp.net won't allow you to have the same name, be sure to give different name on your vb class and web form. Thanks :))